# Chart.js error: type lacks a call signature '((...items: number[]) => number) | ((...items: ChartPoint[]) => number)' in Angular

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular7, chart.js2

When deployed angular app to `Heroku`, I am getting an error

> error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((...items: number[]) => number) | ((...items: ChartPoint[]) => number)' has no compatible call signatures.

But I don't have such type of code inside this component the error is showing. So this seems the chart.js type lack issue or mismatch `@types/chart.js` version.

Following versions are being used

```
"chart.js": "^2.8.0",
"@types/chart.js": "^2.7.52"
```

**Update**

```
<div style="display: block;">
    <canvas #myChart baseChart 
            [datasets]="lineChartData" 
            [labels]="lineChartLabels" 
            [options]="lineChartOptions"
            [colors]="lineChartColors" 
            [legend]="lineChartLegend" 
            [chartType]="lineChartType"
          (chartClick)="onChartClick($event)">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

in .ts file

```
this.lineChartData[0].data = [0]
this.lineChartData[0].data = [1]
this.lineChartData[0].data = [2]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually `[datasets]="lineChartData"` has two types. One is `number[]` and other is `ChartPoint[]` so to store data as number we need to type-cast data as

```
(this.lineChartData[0].data as number[]).push(1)
```

HTML

```
<div style="display: block;">
    <canvas #myChart baseChart [datasets]="lineChartData"></canvas>
</div>
```